# Need User Count on Facebook Application to solve Facebook Alert Rate Limit Reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook application which gets alert "**Rate Limit Reached**".

**APP has reached 100% of the hourly rate limit. All API calls to your app will fail until your app falls below the throttling limit.**

Here's a breakdown of the methods causing your app to hit the rate limit:
By Call Count:

```
GET {page-id}/posts 277%

GET {page-name-id} 141%

GET {page-name-id}/posts 11%

GET {page-id} 3%
```

As per the rate limit to hit the calls : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/

We are allowed to hit ***200 calls / hour*** per user in aggregate. Thus If I get the total number of user using the application I can multiple it with 200 and be sure to no exceed the hits on Facebook API.

```
Allowed API Hits = 200 * (Count Of User Installed The APP)
```

How can I get the count of user who have installed the Facebook Application ?
Can anyone help with the graph API to get user count using the application ?

Comment: i would rather try to lower the amount of API calls. usually, you do not hit limits unless you are doing something wrong. what exactly ARE you doing?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoints you're looking for are within app insights:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights/

Specifically:

- facebook_features_monthly_active_users
- facebook_features_weekly_active_users
- facebook_features_daily_active_users)

Hope this helps! :)